# Couldn't find reference

Tags: android, android-ndk

Here is a screenshot of what I'm getting:
How can I fix this error?

Comment: By the way, you should really pay attention to the warning about APP_PLATFORM being higher than your minSdkVersion. Your native code is only going to work on android-24 and newer.

Comment: Please state the errors. The text on the picture is too small to read. In addition, the text cannot be indexed by search engines for future visitors.

Comment: The error is stated in the body of the question: unknown register name '%eax' is asm.

Answer (score 1):

The log shows that it's building for ARM. `%eax` is x86 asm and won't work on ARM.